# angularjs template edition before show it

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app, and some permissions for users.

I neet to remove a section of my template (I´m using angular route and templates) before present it.

Example: if I have and user with just "create" permission, but not edit permision, I need to remove a div with class like class="edit". But I need to remove that before present the view.

¿Any idea? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the div, you can use ngIf to decide whether the div with class="edit" needs to be shown or not. If you have a boolean which denotes the edit permission of the user like "hasEdit", you can write your div as below:

```
<div *ngIf="hasEdit" class="edit">Your content</div>
```

The above div will be shown only if the hasEdit is true.

Comment: Thanks for answer my friend, but I have a little problem with ng-if; ng-if just hide the code.... and I need to "remove" it because, for example, if I have : <div ng-if="myCondition == false"></div> and I replace the content of ng-if with a 1==1, the div will be presented...

¿Any other idea? thank you ;)

Comment: I don't understand why the content of ngIf needs to be replaced with a "1==1", which obviously is always true.